# Google Oauth 400 error when trying to get auth tokens

Tags: php, google-oauth

I need to fix a PHP Google Auth problem. I am trying to exchange Auth token after receiving a code fails with a 400 bad request.

For the life of me I can't figure it out after reading docs and poring over the code again and again.

Is there something wrong with my url?

```
$url =  'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?&grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_GET['code']."&client_id=".G_CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=".G_CLIENT_SECRET."&redirect_uri=".REDIRECT_URI;
$context = stream_context_create(
            array( 'http' => 
                array('method' => 'POST',
                )
            )
        );          

echo "<Br> url to fetch  : ". $url;
echo "<Br> context to fetch  : ". $context;

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo "<Br> fetch response : ". $response;
```

---

Is code reuse forcing Google to reject my auth token retrieval attempts?

Google doesn't return much info with their 400  error - surely they should give more info?

**Edit 1**

Request header returned by print_r(apache_request_headers ()) -->

```
  Array
      (
      [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
      [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate,sdch
      [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
      [Connection] => keep-alive
      [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=ec0b5ff920282245f7ce6d194ba36bd1; _ga=GA1.2.1973782149.1384923620
      [Host] => lxxxxxxr.com
      [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
     )
```

Response header returned by print_r(apache_response_headers()) -->

```
  Array
  (
  [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.4.20
  [Expires] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
  [Cache-Control] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  [Pragma] => no-cache
  [Content-type] => text/html
  )
```

response Body -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang=en>
   <meta charset=utf-8>
   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
   <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
    <style> ***some style info***    </style>
     <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif               alt=Google></a>
     <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
       <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

**Edit 2 - Solution :**

---

Well I have a solution after comparing the output of the google-api-php-client example that worked with mine.

In simple words my url is constructed wrong. It was constructed as a GET query( which is how Linkedin does its Oauth inspite of their docs claiming that they want POST)

Since this is a POST request my url should have been

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Then I needed to put the query params as part of the content header. So the main working code snippet is

```
$params = array('code' => $_GET['code'],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://carrotleads.com/',
                'client_id' => G_CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret' => G_CLIENT_SECRET,
                );  
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$postBody = http_build_query($params);
$requestHttpContext["content"] = $postBody;
$requestHttpContext["method"] = 'POST';

$options = array( 'http' => $requestHttpContext );
$context = stream_context_create( $options );       

echo '<Br>Your request: <pre>'. print_r($url, true) . '</pre>';  
echo '<Br>Your options: <pre>'. print_r( $options, true) . '</pre>';

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo 'Your response_data: <pre>'. print_r($response, true) . '</pre>';
```

---

Other Info

Google's lib sets lot more headers ( from the Google_HttpStreamIO.php ). The important code snippets paraphrased :)

```
$DEFAULT_HTTP_CONTEXT = array(
 "follow_location" => 0,
 "ignore_errors" => 1,
);
$DEFAULT_SSL_CONTEXT = array(
 "verify_peer" => true,
);
$default_options = stream_context_get_options(stream_context_get_default());
$requestHttpContext = array_key_exists('http', $default_options) ?
    $default_options['http'] : array();

$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$params = array('code' => $_GET['code'],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://carrotleads.com/xxxxxxxxxx',
                'client_id' => G_CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret' => G_CLIENT_SECRET,
                );  
$postBody = http_build_query($params);
$postsLength = strlen($postBody);
$requestHeaders = array_merge( array('content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), array('content-length' => $postsLength));
$headers = "";
foreach($requestHeaders as $k => $v) {
   $headers .= "$k: $v\n";
}
$requestHttpContext["header"] = $headers;
$requestHttpContext["content"] = $postBody;
$requestHttpContext["method"] = 'POST';

$requestSslContext = array_key_exists('ssl', $default_options) ?
    $default_options['ssl'] : array();

if (!array_key_exists("cafile", $requestSslContext)) {
  $requestSslContext["cafile"] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacerts.pem';
}
$options = array("http" => array_merge(self::$DEFAULT_HTTP_CONTEXT,
                                             $requestHttpContext),
                 "ssl" => array_merge(self::$DEFAULT_SSL_CONTEXT,
                                      $requestSslContext));

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response_data = file_get_contents($url,
                                   false,
                                   $context);
```

---

All these additional headers are not needed to exchange Auth token but if you want to do it to standards, that's the way to go, including sending across a certificate file.

If you need lots of to and fro Google API requests you are better off using the well-written Google lib, if not it may be overkill and the above code snippets should help out.

In hindsight I feel silly for not picking up the POST vs GET request difference, live and learn; after 2 days of poring over this, I am relieved.

Comment: Paste the http request and response.

Comment: So "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.". Sorry but I'm crap at reading other people's code. You can figure it out yourself by dumping the actual http request (so you can look at stuff like the correct URI encoding of parameters) and comparing it with the equivalent request in the Oauth Playground. That's the way I sold all of my oauth related issues during development.

Comment: Well I did all that including urlencode the params, compared the params with the OAuth playground and none of that helped. Looked like I was missing something else undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with CURL request. In the `GoogleAnalyticsAPI.class.php > class Http > function curl (around line 720)` add one more option to stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make the request to Google for `/o/oauth2/token`, this must be a POST.  Just changing the method to POST isn't enough, you need to also remove the content from the query string and instead actually put in the body of the request.

I would strongly recommend using the Google provided PHP library (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) which will take care of this for you.

If you do need to do this by hand, try:

1. Remove everything from "?" onwards from the query string.
2. Create your own body, making sure you URL encode each value: `"grant_type=" . urlencode($_GET['code']) . (etc..)`
3. Include a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header and a `Content-Length: nnn` header (if PHP doesn't do the latter automatically.
4. And yes, pretty sure this will only work once per authorization code, and that they have a pretty short lifetime.

Comment: Thanks mate. Using the google lib worked but I have no clue why and I am now digging into its codebase to figure out why.. Will update here once I figure it out.
I had done the url encoding of params etc but none of that helped. Didn't try the content type header but was reusing my linked in Oauth technique and it worked fine, so never assumed this could be a problem. Will try this too.
Hence my point that Google should return better errors instead of just just blind malformed request.
Thanks for your helpful response. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue this way, when you are using PHP version then older 5.5.0

```
<?php
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')):
    function curl_reset($ch){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    }
endif;
```